# How do I identify as a specific domain user for integrated authentication with jdbc?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, windows-authentication

I'm looking to run an automated proccess, which will log in to SQL Server as one of several specific database users. The users may, but most often won't, match the UID that has started the process.

How do i specify the uid/password to use for a given SQLServer jdbc connection, when authenticating with Windows Authentication, from a process running under a user which has a different uid?